# Need an advice for a background effect

Tags: javascript, css, ecmascript-6

### I am making a browser game.

[image: Game Image]

The background is kind of big enough to just subtly scroll down as the user scrolls. It's a rather long scroll so having a fixed background is kind of boring, and if the background isn't fixed, it quickly turns to white space as it isn't big enough to cover the entire game content.

**I want to make background scroll, in the opposite direction of the user scroll, but very subtly for a nice effect**

How is this effect I explained above called? I know jquery can probably do that but I avoid using jquery. I'm pretty good with vanilla javascript, I just need a little help on where to start. Should I make the background and the game content 2 separate divs, and when user scrolls through the game content the background also scrolls a little? Can this be done with just CSS?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding background-attachment: fixed; as CSS property or as understood by your question, you might need parallax-effect. Follow the link https://materializecss.com/parallax-demo.html

Comment: Parallax... That's the exact thing I tried to describe! I already see there are countless examples on the web. Thanks for answering this rather pointless question :) Cheers!